# Signal handling, sigaction return errno 2

Tags: c, macos

any idea why sigaction will set errno 2?

this is my code

```
struct sigaction act;
struct sigaction oldact;

act.sa_sigaction = my_handler;
act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO | SA_64REGSET;

sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);

if (sigaction(SIGBUS, &act, &oldact) != -1) {
    printf("[-] failed to install signal handler, %d", errno);
}
```

Comment: You have the `if` condition backward: `sigaction` returns a nonzero value on _failure_.  That should be `if (sigaction(SIGBUS, &act, &oldact)) { /* report error */ }`.

Comment: Also, we don't know which errno numbers correspond to which actual error conditions on your system.  Never print raw errno numbers.  Your `printf` should read `printf("[-] failed to install handler for SIGBUS: %s\n", strerror(errno));` to get a meaningful error message.  (`strerror` is declared in `string.h`.)

Comment: Oh crap, I didn't even notice that. Thanks A lot!! :)